# date time conversion seems off

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I encounter situation like this where I try to add Millisecond into my DateTime.

[image]

In some cases, it didn't give me the exact number and it got rounded to something else.
Is it normal ?

```
          CONVERT(varchar(125), dateadd(millisecond,ms,datetime), 21) as ZDateTimeMs
```

Comment: Are you using the `datetime2` data type in SQL Server? The legacy `datetime` data type has a 1/300th second (3.333 millisecond) resolution for... [Sybase and UNIX reasons](https://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc32300.1600/doc/html/san1390612192030.html).

Comment: Please don't use images for data, use formatted text.

Answer (score 1):

From [`datetime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#rounding-of-datetime-fractional-second-precision):

`datetime` values are rounded to increments of .000, .003, or .007 seconds, as shown in the following table.

User-specified value    System stored value

```
01/01/98 23:59:59.999   1998-01-02 00:00:00.000
01/01/98 23:59:59.995

01/01/98 23:59:59.996

01/01/98 23:59:59.997

01/01/98 23:59:59.998   1998-01-01 23:59:59.997
01/01/98 23:59:59.992

01/01/98 23:59:59.993

01/01/98 23:59:59.994   1998-01-01 23:59:59.993
01/01/98 23:59:59.990

01/01/98 23:59:59.991   1998-01-01 23:59:59.990
```

Comment: So, I should be creating a different data type ?

Comment: It seems declaring it as a STRING like what I have done probably resolve the automatic rounding behavior.

Comment: @user3015739 using a string for datetimes will cause you pain for the lifetime of the system. As the comment below your question says, the correct solution is to use `datetime2`.